# Calculus with interest rates

Tags: calculus, probability, finance

> Suppose a person will start academic studies on a private university
>   in exactly $3$ years. The academic studies takes $4$ years and in the
>   beginning of each of these four years the person has to pay $8000$
>   tuition fees. How much money would the person need at least, if her
>   money out aside has an interest rate of $5\%$ (using exp. interest
>   payment)?

My idea was the following:

$$C(t) = C(0)(1+r)^t,$$ with $C(t)=32000$, since in the end the person will need 32000. Applying above equation I get

$$32000 = C(0)(1+0.05)^7$$ and therefore C(0) = 22741.80.

Is this approach correct or does it have to be solved differently? Thanks for you help.

Comment: You have to take the timing of the payments into account.  For example, the fourth years interest is just on $C(4)-8000$, not on $C(4)$.  Easier, I think, to do it numerically.

Comment: A suggestion:  first compute (numerically) the amount she'll need at the start of the fourth year (the first year she'll have to make a payment).  Once you know that figure your method will get you the present value back to today.

Comment: My first idea then would be $8000=(C(0)-8000)(1+0.05)$, i.e. $C(0)=15619.05$, so based on she would make the payment of 8000 euro the first year and is going to need 8000 next year, she's goanna need $15619.05$ at the beginning of the year...does this lead me somewhere?

Comment: What are first three years good for? Is the money there at the beginning, and generating $5\%$ interest during these three years? The next four years the sum gets reduced but still generates interest with the remaining money?

Comment: That's how I've understood it, but the example isn't more specific..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The capital at the beginning of year $t$ is:
\begin{align}
C(0) &= C \\
C(1) &= C (1 + r) \\
C(2) &= C (1 + r)^2 \\
C(3) &= C (1 + r)^3 - 8000 \\
C(4) &= (C (1 + r)^3 - 8000)(1 + r) - 8000 \\
C(5) &= ((C (1 + r)^3 - 8000)(1 + r) - 8000)(1 + r) - 8000 \\
C(6) &= (((C (1 + r)^3 - 8000)(1 + r) - 8000)(1 + r) - 8000) (1+r) - 8000 = 0
\end{align}
Solving for $C$ in the last equation:
$$
0 = (((C (1 + r)^3 - 8000)(1 + r) - 8000)(1 + r) - 8000) (1+r) - 8000 \iff \\
(8000 / (1 + r)) = ((C (1 + r)^3 - 8000)(1 + r) - 8000)(1 + r) - 8000 \iff \\
((8000 / (1 + r)) + 8000) / (1+r) = (C (1 + r)^3 - 8000)(1 + r) - 8000 \iff \\
((((8000 / (1 + r)) + 8000) / (1+r)) + 8000) / (1+r) = C (1 + r)^3 - 8000 \iff \\
((((((8000 / (1 + r)) + 8000) / (1+r)) + 8000) / (1+r)) + 8000) / (1+r)^3 = C
$$
I told this my friend Ruby

```
irb(main):001:0> x1 = 8000.0 / 1.05
=> 7619.047619047618
irb(main):002:0> x2 = (x1 + 8000) / 1.05
=> 14875.283446712017
irb(main):003:0> x3 = (x2 + 8000) / 1.05
=> 21785.984234963827
irb(main):004:0> x4 = (x3 + 8000) / 1.05**3
=> 25730.253091427556
irb(main):005:0> C = x4
=> 25730.253091427556
```

and also tested this result with her help

```
irb(main):007:0> c1 = C * 1.05
=> 27016.765745998935
irb(main):008:0> c2 = C * 1.05**2
=> 28367.60403329888
irb(main):009:0> c3 = C * 1.05**3 - 8000
=> 21785.984234963827
irb(main):010:0> c4 = c3 * 1.05 - 8000
=> 14875.28344671202
irb(main):011:0> c5 = c4 * 1.05 - 8000
=> 7619.04761904762
irb(main):012:0> c6 = c5 * 1.05 - 8000
=> 1.8189894035458565e-12
```

which looks reasonable to me, neglecting rounding issues.

Comment: I had a Similar one but until C(7), I think that was my Problem...thank You!